# ASP.Net Core JwtBearerAuthentication failure redirect - can I specify the HTTP method?

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm trying to handle authentication failures for requests containing a jwt.  I understand in order to get the failure reason/statuscode back to the client I need to perform a redirect, as in the `OnAuthenticationFailed` handler below:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
    Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect($"/api/session/error?message={context.Exception.Message}");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

The target (`context.Response.Redirect()` above) of the redirect is defined with `[HttpGet]` attribute, but is never being hit due to the original request (in this case) being http PUT.  This method is reached if the original request is http GET:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("Error")]
public IActionResult AuthenticationError([FromQuery]string message)
{
}
```

I understand why this is happening: The `context.Response.Redirect()` method accepts the 'location' only and reuses the original request's http method (which is a PUT in this case).

Is there a way I can specify the redirect's http method?  Or am i misunderstanding how redirection for an authentication failure handling works?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution would be to let asp.net core handle it. Cause then the client would get back a 401 directly.

And setting `AutomaticChallenge = true`

So

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
});
```